# how to add column of data from a loop into an existing file on python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x

here is my code so far

```
    with open("data.txt","r+") as inData:
        for line in inData:
            line=line.strip()
            x,y,z,t=line.split("\t",3)
            newY=float(y)
            newtemp=newY+237.15
            print(newtemp)
```

I want to take all the lines i get from newtemp to create a new column in the existing data.txt file.  I want to do the same for one of the other variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do create new column in csv file using python by shifting one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845329/how-do-create-new-column-in-csv-file-using-python-by-shifting-one-row)

Comment: Although note that if the input and output files are the same, you need to either: read the input file completely into memory before writing to the output file (non-atomic, as the output file will be clobbered when you open in in write mode), or write to a temporary file, then if that succeeds rename the temporary file and delete the old file.